# Can kinetic and potential energy of a swinging pendulum both be zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

I am currently reading Jakob Schwichtenberg's *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics* for some review, and I can't seem to reconcile one of the claims in the beginning of the book. He states that the total energy in a system is $E=T+V$, where $V$ is potential energy and $T$ is kinetic energy given by $T=\frac{1}{2}m\dot q^2$ (he uses the notation where $\dot q$ is the time derivative of the position vector, velocity).

In the example, we are shown a swinging pendulum which traces out an arc of motion and constantly transfers energy between kinetic and potential. Thus, at the top of the arc, $T=0$, since there is no motion in this instant. However, shouldn't potential energy be at its maximum? That is, shouldn't $E=V$? In the diagram, he has stated that "$T=0$ since $V=0$." But I don't understand how this is possible, why would kinetic and potential energy both be zero?

Note — I apologize for having written on the page before trying to post this problem so it should be stated that the vertical dotted line as well as the two *solid* arcs (one black, one red) on the right-hand side are mine. Everything else in the figure, including the remark, is what's actually printed in the book.

Thank you all in advance!

[image: page from Schwichtenberg]

Comment: Can one not choose any position as the zero of potential energy?

Comment: As you mentioned when $T=0$, $V=E=0$. This is possible if we choose the reference point of potential energy as highest height the weight can reach. In this case $h_{\text{max}}=0$ and any height below that is negative with respect to this reference position. Below that line (below the highest height line) potential energy will be negative since $mgh < mgh_{\text{max}} = 0$. So, that means when $T=0$, $V=E=0$ is the maximum energy configuration for this system.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN I see, so kinetic energy must be positive (because of the $\dot q^2$), but potential energy can assume negative values in order to cancel and therefore could just as well have its maximum be given by $V=0$. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @jinks908 Yes, you are right. At any time, the systems total mechanical energy is always $T+V=E=0$. When $T \ne 0$ so $h \ne h_{\text{max}}$, $T > 0$ and $V < 0$ and their values are equal, so they cancel each others, giving us total energy as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, at the top of the arc, $T=0$, since there is no motion in this instant.

Yes. The smallest that $T$ can be is zero, since by definition $T$ is non-negative.

> However, shouldn't potential energy be at its maximum?

Yes.

N.b., the maximum of the potential energy *can* be zero. (This just means the potential energy will be negative when the kinetic energy is positive.)

> That is, shouldn't $E=V$?

Yes, when $T=0$ you have $E=V$. If $V$ also is zero at this same point you have $E=V=0$ when $T=0$. If, later on, you find that $T=100$, at this same time you will also find that $V=-100$ and $E=0$.

> In the diagram, he has stated that "$T=0$ since $V=0$." But I don't understand how this is possible, why would kinetic and potential energy both be zero?

You are free to add an arbitrary constant to the expression for the total energy. If the author has chosen $V=0$ when $T=0$ this means as the author has chosen their arbitrary constant such that the total energy is (always) zero. This means, for example, that when the kinetic energy is positive, the potential energy is negative. It is perfectly fine for a potential energy value to be negative.

---

> Can kinetic and potential energy of a swinging pendulum both be zero?

Yes. See the discussion above.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear. I think I just found it odd that he chose 0 to be the total energy of the system, and I took this to mean *there is no kinetic/potential energy at all*. So we must have $T\geq0$ since velocity is squared, but $V$ can be negative depending on how we want to frame our problem. For example, if at the bottom of the arc, $T=100$ and $V=-100$, we are merely saying that $-100$ is the minimum potential energy of the system?

Comment: "For example, if at the bottom of the arc, T=100 and V=−100 , we are merely saying that −100 is the minimum potential energy of the system?" Yes, this is correct.

Comment: As another example, suppose I am initially holding the pendulum bob stationary at a fixed angle $\theta_0$. At this instant the kinetic energy is $T = 0 =\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$ and the potential energy $mgh_0$ is whatever constant value I would like (since $h_0$ is relative to an arbitrary reference height), but let us again make the choice that the potential energy is zero at this point (i.e., we define this point as $h_0=0$. At the bottom of the swing the potential energy will be $-mg\ell\cos(\theta) = mgh_B$ and the kinetic energy will be $+mg\ell\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}mv_B^2$.

Comment: Okay, so in this scenario, potential energy is at a maximum at the height $h_{0}$, and equal to 0. But does this change if we instead *push* the pendulum down rather than just release it? Because at that point, the pendulum *would* reach a height greater than $h_{0}$ due to the extra force. So then potential energy at $h_{0}$ could still be 0 as defined, but would that no longer be the maximum?

Comment: Yes. If you push it down you are giving it a non-zero velocity (and therefore non-zero kinetic energy) when it is at height $h_0$ (which we already agreed was set to zero by our convention $h_0=0$. So, on the other side it will swing up higher than $h_0$, it will instead swing up to $h_1 = T_0/mg$.